# How to install mapnik on SLES 11 64 bit?

Tags: linux, installation, suse, mapnik

For a customer I have to install a django webserver on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11, 64 bit (short: SLES 11). Our application makes use of mapnik 0.7.0. My development environment is Ubunto 10.44.

How do I install mapnik 0.7.0 on my SLES 11 machine? My first difficulty is to compile boost. Maybe it's handy to use SUSE Linux Enterprise Desktop, or OpenSUSE to compile components?

Several instructions on the web:

Official Mapnik instructions:
http://trac.mapnik.org/wiki/LinuxInstallation

For SLES 10:
http://lists.berlios.de/pipermail/mapnik-users/2010-January/002810.html

(for some redhat distro) 
http://gis.638310.n2.nabble.com/Bulding-mapnik-on-RHEL5-td4612325.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've started a wiki page for Mapnik on Suse here: http://trac.mapnik.org/wiki/OpenSuseInstallation.

I don't have access to SUSE proper - so hopefully a guide built for the latest Open Suse release will work.

I recommend installing Mapnik 0.7.1 (latest official release).

If you have specific problems with compiling boost then I recommend sending a mail to mapnik-users and I can update the above wiki page with any relevant info.

Comment: Great! My colleage found the page as well. He found the way and updated the page!